# Display folder structure using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list folder name and sub folder name using mysql query. The depth of subfolders is unknown. That is a parent folder may have n level of sub folders. Please refer the sample folder structue below:

```
.
├── PHP
│   ├── Developer
│   │   ├── Junior
│   │   └── Senior
│   └── Tester
├── Java
│   └── Test Engineer
└── Android
```

The folder structure may vary..

My table is look like

[image]

I want to load the folder name in a select box like parent and their child manner.

```
  PHP
  Developer
  Junior
  Senior
  Tester
  Java
  Test Engineer
  Android
```

**What I tried?**

```
$fOption="";
$parentFolders = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jp_emp_folder WHERE parent_id='0' AND emp_id='".$empId."'");
while($parentRows = $db->fetch_array($parentFolders)){
    $fOption .= "<option value='".$parentRows['id']."'>".$parentRows['folder_name']."</option>";
    $child = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jp_emp_folder WHERE parent_id='".$parentRows['id']."' AND emp_id='".$empId."'");
    while($childRows = $db->fetch_array($child)){
        $fOption .= "<option value='".$childRows['id']."'>".$childRows['folder_name']."</option>";
    }
} 
echo $fOption;
```

I know this only give the 2 level folder structure. But I have n level. How can I acheive this? Please suggest..

Comment: Keyword: *Recursive*. Not suggested to use this approach to construct your hierarchy, as the overhead of DB will be large. If possible, you can fetch the whole structure into an multi-dimensional arrays. By recursively reading the array, you can construct the tree easily & efficiently.

Comment: Recursive programming could be a good solution for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to construct your hierarchy.

**Step 1: Build up the $data in PHP**

```
$data = array();
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jp_emp_folder WHERE emp_id=" . (int)$empId);
while($rows = $db->fetch_array($results)) {
  $data[$row['id']] = $rows;
}
```

**Step 2: Recursively read the $data to construct hierarchy**

```
function readData($parent_id = 0) {
        global $data; // I'm just lazy, avoid using "global"
        foreach($data as $id => $item) {
            if($parent_id > 0 && $item['parent_id'] != $parent_id) {
                continue;
            }
            echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $item['folder_name'] . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
            unset($data[$id]); // Remove echo-ed contents
            if($item['parent_id'] > 0) {
                readData((int)$id);
            }
        }
    }

readData(); // Start reading $data
```

which will output the following:

```
<option value="1">PHP</option>
<option value="2">Java</option>
<option value="3">Android</option>
<option value="4">Test Engineer</option>
<option value="5">Developer</option>
<option value="7">Junior</option>
<option value="6">Tester</option>
```

Comment: Why? What's your logic? Please explain.

Comment: look the table in my question, `Junior` have the `parent_id` `5` which is `Developer`

Comment: I trying to get the output as parent its child and its child (if any) and so on..Your output gives all parent nodes then child manner. My question says all..please refer..

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
$all_folders = $db->query("SELECT * FROM jp_emp_folder WHERE emp_id='".$empId."'");
$array_column = array_column($all_folders, 'parent_id');        
$all_parent0_dir = array_keys($array_column, "0");  //get all base folders

foreach ($all_parent0_dir as $value) { 
    $dir = $all_folders[$value];
    echo '<option value="'.$dir['id'].'">'.$dir['foler_name'].'</option>';
    $parent_id = $dir['id'];
    $nodeNumber = 1;
    $lastElem = FALSE;//is this last element of the folder
    $nodeArray = [];//save all the nodes of the folder
    while ( $parent_id != $dir['id'] || $lastElem == FALSE) {
        /*************************************************************/
        //get details of a specific folder
        $last = 1;
        $sub_dir_ids = array_keys($array_column, $parent_id); 
        if($sub_dir_ids)
        { 
            $sub_dir = isset($sub_dir_ids[$nodeNumber-1])? $sub_dir_ids[$nodeNumber-1] : null;
            if($sub_dir){ 
                $res = $all_folders[$sub_dir];
                echo '<option value="'.$res['id'].'">'.$res['foler_name'].'</option>';
                if($res){$last = 0; }                       
            }
        }
        /*************************************************************/
        if($last == 1){           
            if($parent_id != $dir['id']){//if $parent_id didn't reach the first element (starting point)
                $lastElement = array_pop($nodeArray);
                $parent_id = $lastElement[0];
                $nodeNumber = $lastElement[1] + 1;
            }else{$lastElem = TRUE;}
        }else{
           $lastElem = FALSE;
           array_push($nodeArray, array($parent_id,$nodeNumber));
           $parent_id = $res['id'];//$parent_id for inner folder
           $nodeNumber = 1;//go to next step - inner folder
        }
    }            
}
```

Output

```
<option value="1">PHP</option>
<option value="5">DEVELOPER</option>
<option value="7">JUNIOR</option>
<option value="8">SENIOR</option>
<option value="6">TESTER</option>
<option value="2">JAVA</option>
<option value="4">TEST ENG</option>
<option value="3">ANDROID</option>
```

Comment: That's bad. Excessive DB fetching is not advised.

Comment: I didn't understand, what you mean by 'Excessive DB fetching'. Could you please explain?

Comment: Yes, in your every recursive loop, you query DB once. That makes a lot of unnecessary queries which you can fetch all data in 1 query.

Comment: @Raptor, I have removed DB query in loop and used array_keys function.   Do you think this will course memory problem. Could you check it?